# SQLSERVER Select rows as columns even if there is no enough rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, crosstab

I have a problem to build a query. After searching on stackoverflow i think i need a crosstab. But i don't know what exactly is this. I think it would be quicker if i show you a simplified version of my problem. I would be glad if you could point me to right direction.

This is example of data:

```
ColumnIDToGroup  Value
-----------------------
  1              AAAA
  1              BBBB
  2              AAAA
  2              BBBB
  2              CCCC
```

I need to build a query to get the data in this format:

```
ColumnIDToGroup  Value1  Value2   Value3  Value4  Value5
------------------------------------------------------------
  1              AAAA     BBBB   'Empty'  'Empty' 'Empty'
  2              AAAA     BBBB    CCCC    'Empty' 'Empty'
```

As a workarround, I could accept this output, if it is simple to build (when a value is not null, it always have the same size)

```
ColumnIDToGroup      ValueConcat  
-------------------------------------
  1              AAAABBBB************
  2              AAAABBBBCCCC********
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(ColumnIDToGroup INT,Value VARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT  1,             'AAAA'
UNION ALL
 SELECT   1,              'BBBB'
UNION ALL
 SELECT   2,              'AAAA'
UNION ALL
 SELECT   2,              'BBBB'
UNION ALL
SELECT    2,              'CCCC'
```

Now select the rows from the table, create a column for Value1, Value2 etc and select the extra columns for Value4,Value5 by UNION all and set text to Empty.

```
SELECT *,
'Value'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  ColumnIDToGroup ORDER BY VALUE)AS VARCHAR(3)) COL
INTO #NEWTABLE
FROM #TEMP
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Empty','Value3'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Empty','Value3'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Empty','Value4'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Empty','Value4'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'Empty','Value5'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Empty','Value5'
```

Now get the columns for pivot

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + COL + ']', '[' + COL + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT COL FROM #NEWTABLE) PV 
               ORDER BY COL
```

Now pivot the query

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT *   
                 FROM #NEWTABLE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(VALUE)
                 FOR COL IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY ColumnIDToGroup;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98b79/2) to view the result

If you want in the second specified format, you can use the below query

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *        
    FROM #TEMP
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'****'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'****'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'****'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'****'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'****'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'****'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'****'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,'***'
)
SELECT  DISTINCT C2.ColumnIDToGroup,  
-- Convert to single row for each ColumnIDToGroup
        SUBSTRING(
        (SELECT ' ' + CTE.VALUE
        FROM CTE 
        WHERE C2.ColumnIDToGroup=ColumnIDToGroup
        ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN CTE.VALUE = 'AAAA' THEN 1
             WHEN CTE.VALUE = 'BBBB' THEN 2
             WHEN CTE.VALUE = 'CCCC' THEN 3
        ELSE 4
        END
        FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) ValueConcat 
        FROM CTE C2
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dad3b/2) to view result

Comment: Feel free to ask for any changes. @Rumpel

Comment: First of all thanks for the help. The only problem I see there is the UNION. The idea behind this is to create a view or a stored procedure to consult the data in a simplest way. I don't know the data in table #TEMP, because it changes. The application behind this is constantly inserting, updating an deleting rows. So I don't know how the construct the union dynamically. I mean, if I use your code in a store procedure for example, and after that, I insert one row (for example: ID:1,Value:CCCC) i get 2 rows with the same value en COL. (continue in next comment)

Comment: Also If i delete one row (For example ID:1, Value:AAAA), I won't have any COL with Value1. However i see the idea behind of this, i think that, thanks to you, i could solve this last problem by myself :D

Comment: Yes. For the given sample in question it will work. If the values keep on changing in table, you have to do 'Empty' and **** dynamic.